# Derivative of a norm

Tags: calculus, vectors

I was wondering if there was a formula for the derivative of a norm (||V(t)||)' (where V(t) is some vector function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$).

Using the dot product rule, I got $$(||V(t)||^{2})' = (V(t) \cdot V(t))' = 2V(t) \cdot V'(t)$$ and, letting g(t) = ||V(t)||, $$ (||V(t)||^{2})' = (g(t)^{2})' = 2g(t)g'(t) = 2||V(t)||*(||V(t)||)'$$

Combining both equations gives $$(||V(t)||)' = \frac{V(t) \cdot V'(t)}{||V(t)||}$$

I just wanted to check with someone if this is correct, or if I've done something wrong somewhere. Thank you!

Edit: Forgot to put in dots for some of the dot products

Comment: I think it is correct if $V(t)\neq0$ for any $t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reasoning is correct but you should end up with a scalar so your result is wrong.

I will denote $\phi(t)=\| \mathbf{v}(t) \|$.
Thus $\phi^2=\| \mathbf{v}(t) \|^2
=\mathbf{v}(t)^T \mathbf{v}(t)$.
It follows the equality
$$2\phi d\phi 
= 2 \mathbf{v}(t)^Td\mathbf{v}(t)
= 2 \mathbf{v}(t)^T\frac{\partial \mathbf{v}(t)}{\partial t} dt
$$
From here, the derivative wrt time $t$ is
$$
\dot{\phi}(t)=\frac{1}{\phi}
\mathbf{v}(t)^T \dot{\mathbf{v}}(t)
$$

Comment: Okay, thanks! I believe I just forgot to put in dots for two of the dot products in my solution